# send data between two component whose parent component is same

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]

- I have two child component `product-list.component`,
  `product-details.component` whose parent component is
  `products.component`.

  - In `product-list.component` , I am displaying list of dummy products.
  - In `product-details.component`, I want to display clicked product details.
    After clicking the list, I am getting selected product in parent component(products.component) .

*I want to display the selected product in `product-details.component`.

[Link of project is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cegxr4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. The output of the `ProductListComponent` becomes the input of the `ProductDetailsComponent`. For that, you just have to set the input of your `ProductDetailsComponent` in your `products.component.html`:

```
<app-product-details [detailRowInput]="detailSingleRow"></app-product-details>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-og98q4?embed=1&file=src/app/mycomponents/products/products.component.html)

Comment: Thanks @Kim Kern, I was stuck on this for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

For the basics, what you should do is:

- Check this link: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
- catch `click` event, and assign the `product` to an `@Output` variable.
- Now on your parent component HTML, listen to the `@Output` event (you will get the `product` that was `click`ed.)
- Now pass this `product` to the `productDetail` using `@Input` as explained in the link above.

  Code of the product component will be like:

  ```
  <product-list (itemSelected)="loadDetails(any)">
  </product-list>

  <product-detail [selectedItem]="any">
  <product-detail>
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Safi Ullah

Comment: Welcome :) @yash